# How to add a button to command in overflow menu in codenameone?

Tags: java, button, menu, overflow, codenameone

I am trying to add a button to a command on the overflow menu (three dots).  The code below works for a side menu (hamburger) but doesn't for overflow.

```
Command rightMenuItem1 = new Command("Add Item");
Button item = new Button("Add Item");
item.setCommand(it); //it is a command object
rightMenuItem1.putClientProperty("SideComponent",item);
myToolbar.addCommandToOverflowMenu(rightMenuItem1);
```

How can I do it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
rightMenuItem1.putClientProperty("SideComponent",item);
```

You can't place components in the overflow